# Node.js callback is not a function

Tags: node.js

Running a simple redis test

```
var redis = require(__dirname+'/server/redis.js');
    redis.redisTest(function(res){
        RedisState = res;
    });
```

redis.js

```
redisTest: function(callback){
    GameDBCon.set('my test key', 'my test value');
    GameDBCon.get('my test key', function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            callback(false);
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
        console.log('GET result ->' + result);
        callback(true);
    });
},
```

error from redis.js at callback(true);

callback is not a function, I see a lot of similar issues like this but its not making much sense. Additionally I have similar code that does work.

Shouldn't this callback work?

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code . Can you `console.log(result)` & `callback`

Comment: For starters, change `throw error` to `return`.  You've already communicated back the error state to the callback.  There is no need to `throw` there and it won't be caught by anything either.  But, you do need to `return` there to avoid call the `callback(true)` later or add an `else` clause to your `if`.

Comment: @Helpinghand "GET result ->my test value" does get outputted but then crashes at callback(true);

Comment: @jfriend00 first thing first and thats to remove the error message. i am aware of the need to use retun